# Primefaces 3.4.2 Issue with Datatable Sorting

Tags: sorting, datatable, primefaces

Recently i have upgraded to latest prime faces version 3.4.2 , i was able to not sort editable column in data table,it was working fine with 3.4.1 and 3.4 ,is it a bug? did any one encounter this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has some problem when i run it on local machine even though i cleared the project,build directory.it works fine on server site.